# Falling body hits edge of table causing it to rotate, which force causes this rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

If a body falls hitting an edge parallel to itself, is it the normal force that causes this rotation, if so how does one calculate this force as the body doesn't come to a complete stop it barely even causes acceleration in the linear sense?

Comment: Hint: Net torque about the center of mass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about a situation like so

[image: fig1]

The force that causes the rotation is the contact force with the edge, which exerts a torque about the center of mass.

Over a short period of time $\Delta t$ this force will modify the velocity and rotation by the following amounts

$$\begin{aligned}
 \Delta v & = - \frac{F}{m} \Delta t \\
 \Delta \omega & = \frac{F d}{I} \Delta t
\end{aligned}$$

where $d$ is the perpendicular distance to the center of mass, $m$ is the mass and $I$ is the mass moment of inertia of the body about the center of mass.

The velocity of the contact point **A** before impact is

$$ v_A = v - \omega d $$

Since the velocity of the contact point after the application of the force must be zero (it cannot penetrate into the edge) it means that the changes in translational velocity $\Delta v$ and rotational velocity $\Delta \omega$ must be related with the following equation

$$ (v+\Delta v) - (\omega + \Delta \omega) d = 0 $$ or $$\Delta v -  d\,\Delta \omega  = -v_A$$

Now plug the values from above to get the equation in terms of the force $F$

$$(- \frac{F}{m} \Delta t) -  d\,(\frac{F d}{I} \Delta t)  = -v_A$$

and solve for the impulse

$$ J = F \Delta t = \left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{d^2}{I} \right)^{-1} v_A $$

As you can see the shorter the impulse lasts, the higher the force needs to be in order to equate to the same r.h.s of this equation.

I like the group $m_{\rm eff} = \left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{d^2}{I} \right)^{-1}$ as the effective mass the contact sees. The closer the contact is to the center of mass the closer the effective mass is to the actual mass. On the other hand, the further away the contact is, the less the effective mass is.

You can also look at the final velocity (and rotation) as a function of the initial velocity (and rotation)

$$ \pmatrix{v^\star \\ \omega^\star} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{m d^2}{I+m d^2} & \frac{I d}{I+m d^2} \\ \frac{m d}{I+m d^2} & \frac{I}{I+m d^2}  \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{v \\ \omega} $$

Comment: Thank you for this clear and comprehensive reply must be the best answer I have received on this forum

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help you to understand if you imagine that the body is stationary and the edge is moving upward and striking the body.

So imagine a baseball bat striking a stationary Frisbee near the edge of the Frisbee.  The Frisbee will be given two components of motion.

1. Translation of the Frisbee will be caused because the contact force is pushing the Frisbee.
2. Rotation of the Frisbee will also result because the bat strikes it at a position other than the Frisbee's center of mass.

The amount of translation vs. rotation is determined by the location of the strike and by the Frisbee's moment of inertia.

Now back to your question about a falling body... the body's fall will be slowed down as a result of hitting the edge (it is accelerated upward just as the Frisbee is accelerated).  The body will also be given a rotation as it continues its fall.

You ask about calculating the contact force.  The force depends on many things, including...

1. The velocity of the body
2. The mass of the body
3. The moment of inertia of the body
4. The compliance of the body and the edge (modulus of elasticity)